# Can we pass a environment variable modified by python script to the outer shell?

Tags: python, shell

For the following python script:

```
import os
os.system('PYTHONPATH=\user\...')
os.system('export PYTHONPATH')
....
```

Is there anyway we can "export" the `PYTHONPATH` variable to the shell after executing this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  When the Python process is launched, it gets its own copy of the environment, copied from the parent shell.  The Python process can only modify the private copy, and changes are not propagated back to the parent process.

If you want to do something like this, the best you can get is to print the shell commands needed to do the desired environment variable changes, e.g.

```
print "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:..."
```

and run the script using

```
eval "$(python myscript.py)"
```

Comment: Yes.  Note that this will work only for shells that recognize the `export VAR=VALUE` syntax.  Some old Bourne-style shells require `VAR=VALUE; export VALUE` (bash, ksh, and zsh will also accept this form), and csh-derived shells require `setenv VAR VALUE`.  One common approach is to have a command-line argument to specify the shell syntax to use; the default can be based on the value of `$SHELL`.

Answer (score 0):

Sven's answer is a good one.

Another possible approach, depending on your requirements, is to invoke a new shell process from the Python script.  Since the new shell is a child of the Python process, it will inherit any environment variables.

Obviously this isn't always what you want to do, but it's an alternative.